# Adding a map legend to a webpage

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, css

On the web page where the map shows (using Mapbox GL) and I want to add legend. The icons in the mapbox map are in a sprite with the details in JSON. I can see the PNG sprite and JSON in the browser console. The JSON looks like:

`"airport-15": {
  "width": 42,
  "height": 42,
  "x": 76,
  "y": 300,
  "pixelRatio": 2,
  "visible": true
}`

What's the best way to create a CSS class for the marker icons? For performance reasons I'm hoping to avoid loading the PNG image a second time.
`.icon-airport-15 {...}`

[Mapbox sprite documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/sprite/)

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet might be helpful:

https://github.com/orangemug/legend-symbol/blob/master/src/util.js#L78-L102

```js
export function mapImageToDataURL (map, icon) {
  if (!icon) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const image = map.style.imageManager.images[icon];
  if (!image) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const canvasEl = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvasEl.width = image.data.width;
  canvasEl.height = image.data.height;
  const ctx = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
  ctx.putImageData(
    new ImageData(
      Uint8ClampedArray.from(image.data.data),
      image.data.width, image.data.height
    ),
    0, 0
  );

  // Not toBlob() because toDataURL is faster and synchronous.
  return canvasEl.toDataURL();
}
```